# How get the value from repetition form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to make a multiple choice for quiz, and the question is from the database and also the answer, so i code the program like this:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="test/hitung">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <?php
        $no = 0;
        foreach ($data_pilihan as $row){
            $no++;
            ?>
            <?php
            if($no == 1){
                $status = "active";
            }else{
                $status = "";
            }
            ?>
            <div class="tab-pane <?php echo $status;?>" role="tabpanel" id="<?php echo "step".$no?>">
                <h3>Pertanyaan</h3>
                <p>This is step 1</p>
                <form action="">
                    <input type="radio" name="<?php echo "pertanyaan".$no?>" value="<?php echo $row->simbol_a?>"><?php echo $row->pernyataan_a?><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="<?php echo "pertanyaan".$no?>" value="<?php echo $row->simbol_b?>"><?php echo $row->pernyataan_b?><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="<?php echo "pertanyaan".$no?>" value="<?php echo $row->simbol_c?>"><?php echo $row->pernyataan_c?><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="<?php echo "pertanyaan".$no?>" value="<?php echo $row->simbol_d?>"><?php echo $row->pernyataan_d?>
                </form>
                <ul class="list-inline" align="center">
                    <?php if($no != 1): ?>
                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Previous</button></li>
                    <?php endif?>
                    <?php if($no != $Jumlah_Data):?>
                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">continue</button></li>
                    <?php endif?>
                    <?php if($no == $Jumlah_Data):?>
                        <li><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary next-step">finish</button></li>
                    <?php endif?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <?php }
        ?>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

but when I try to get a data from the form value of the radio button and then I print, it just show the first value. How can i print or get another or rest of the value?

Comment: What does your code look like to get the 1st value?

Comment: Also, it would be easier to get your values in php if your input names were an array -> `name="pertanyaan[<?php echo $no?>]"`. You could then loop over them -> `foreach($_POST['pertanyaan'] as $key=>$value){....}`

Answer (score 0):

if all the name of the radio buttons are same , you will get only one value

As the Definition is a graphical control element that allows the user to choose only one of a predefined set of mutually exclusive options

For eg: In this case user can select only one out of three options

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
</form>
```

From PHP you can access as - here u get only one selected value

```
<?PHP

$selected_radio = $_POST['gender'];
print $selected_radio;

?>
```

if you need multiple selection you can make use of checkbox

if your case if you need one options out of 4 need to be selected give a common name to radio button

please add if anything is missing